# First-order logic: Understanding quantifiers

Tags: logic

Suppose we have a signature $\sigma=\{E\}$ and a structure $\mathcal{G} = (V(G), E^\mathcal{G})$ where $V(G)$ is the vertex set of a graph $G$ and $E^\mathcal{G}$ is the binary relation symbol for the existence of an edge between two vertices.

Consider the formula $\varphi := \forall x \exists y(E(x, y)). $ The formula says for every vertex $x$, there exists a vertex $y$ such that $\{xy\} \in E(G)$.

Does this mean that $x$ and $y$ can be equal, resulting in a self-loop for every node? Or does the formula implicitly say that $x \neq y$? How should the formula be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit assumption of inequality. One way in which $\varphi$ could be satisfied by $\mathcal{G}$ is if every node has a self-loop, although of course this isn't the *only* way $\varphi$ could be satisfied.

If you want to further demand inequality, you should write $$\forall x\exists y(x\not=y\wedge E(x,y))$$ instead.